# Is it possible to include conditions in equality matrices in scipy.optimize.linprog?

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I am setting up a simple linear optimization where I am minimizing C*x, where C is a cost and x is a variable dependent on several constraints.  The main equality constraint is that x[2]=x[1]+x[25], or alternatively, -x[1]+x[2]-x[25]=0.

But in reality, the actual value of x[25] will be dependent on whether x[25] is positive or negative.  So instead, it should be more like this:

```
if x[25]>0  
-x[1]+x[2]-1.11*x[25]=0  
if x[25]<0  
-x[1]+x[2]-0.9*x[25]=0
```

So, in short, does anyone know whether scipy.optimize,linprog is capable of including conditions on the value of the input matrices, in this case A_eq?
Here's an example of my code:

```
import numpy as np 
import scipy.optimize as spo
f=np.concatenate(np.zeros((24,1)),cost.reshape((24,1))
A=np.vstack((-np.identity(24),np.identity(24)))
b=np.vstack((Max_x,Min_x))
#Aeq repeats several times, but is the same throughout for loop
Aeq=np.append(np.append(np.array([-1,1]),np.zeros((1,22))),np.array(-1)) 
#the last value is what I want to make conditional on the value of x
beq=np.zeros((25,1)) 
bounds_x=np.tile((None,None),24,1)
res=spo.linprog(f,A_ub=A,b_ub=b,A_eq=Aeq,B_eq=beq,bounds=bounds_x)
```

So the main thing I want to change is Aeq such 
 that the final value of Aeq is eff, and eff is dependent on the sign of x.

Comment: Please format the first portion of the question properly (conditionals) including indentation and include in a minimal example

Comment: In general linprog cannot do that. Also, in general this cannot be expressed as LP (without some heavy assumptions). The usual route is introducing binary variables resulting in integer-programming, but there is no solver for that in scipy. If that restriction is only used for this one variable: just solve it twice: one time assuming x is positive, one time it's negative.

Comment: @sascha thanks for the suggestion, I think adding a binary variable seems like a good way to proceed.  But I assume since x[25] is not an integer, it would be a MILP problem with binary variables.  I'm a bit of beginner in LP (and especially MILP), if you have any more suggestions I'd really appreciate it!  Thanks!